# What are the dangers of quick successive file writes?

Tags: c, logging, file-io

I'm working on a logging mechanism for a chat program written in C and I'm unsure about potential dangers related to writing to files.

I'm worried about spam, and how I need to deal with having potentially tens or even hundreds of `fopen`/`fclose` calls per second, and if that's even a worry at all. Right now I have it filling a buffer then writing the buffer's contents to file once it's full, but even that might not mitigate a heavy spam attack unless the buffer is excessively large.

Am I being overly paranoid or is this an issue that needs looking after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdio.h` I/O functions use buffering by default. While you're free to use your own buffer, be aware that you may be over-complicating the process of logging.

If you're planning to open and close a file many times a second, it makes more sense to just keep the file descriptor open. Keeping the file open doesn't prevent you from writing to it in the program, or from reading the log file from a different program (e.g. running your program in the background).

The only thing to be aware of is that with a buffered logging system, the buffer may not be flushed before your program terminates. As in, your buffer (or the one maintained by stdio) may only be partially filled, but a crash causes the buffer's contents to never be written. This might prevent crucial information from being used to debug a crash.

This means that you should figure out how to catch whatever errors are possible, and [flush](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/fflush.html) the output buffer before terminating.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to fopen/fclose every time, you can just leave the files open (if you are worried about something not being written to log files if the program crashes well, this would apply only to the *debug* logs, not the user ones).

That said, just look at what others do!

Normally a deamon writes everything to its log files without worrying about stuff like disk-space, and a cronjob will compress/clean the old ones. The important things, IMO, are that:

- it will not crash if it finishes the disk space for the logs (because well, this would probably be stupid in most of the cases, but YMMV)
- if the user *really* needs it, add an optional anti-spam feature: keep in mind that most of the times the users will simply disable the logging :)